# JSON Encode with [ ]

Tags: php, json

I cant seem to get my json_encode to include brackets..
Any help?

**My code is:**

```
$th = json_encode(array("4" => "four", "8" => "eight"));
echo $th;
```

**and the output is:**

```
{"4":"four","8":"eight","9":"\n"}
```

**The output I need to send to the api is:**

```
[{"4":"four","8":"eight","9":"\n"}]
```

How can I get the brackets in the JSON array?
Thank you!

Comment: Is it perl? php? Please add the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
$th = json_encode(array(array("4" => "four", "8" => "eight", "9" => "\n")));
```

Answer (score 3):

You should do this way:

```
$th = json_encode(array(array("4" => "four", "8" => "eight")));
```

Comment: The issue being that you wanted an array of JSON objects, whereas you were previously just specifying one JSON object (represented as a key-value array in PHP).